# how to filter out in R variables that need to match differing and multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I would like to filter OUT variables that match two (or more) conditions in their 'row format', I was wondering how to do that with `filter`

In the example below I want to filter out the rows where id is M & from the state of 'CA', as well as when the id is F and from the state of PH.

The code below doesn't do that...how can I do this? Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
  name = c('sai','ram','deepika','sahithi','kumar','scott','Don','Lin'),
  gender = c('M','M',NA,'F','M','M','M','F'),
  dob = as.Date(c('1990-10-02','1981-3-24','1987-6-14','1985-8-16',
                  '1995-03-02','1991-6-21','1986-3-24','1990-8-26')),
  state = c('CA','NY',NA,NA,'DC','DW','AZ','PH'),
  row.names=c('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6','r7','r8')
)

df %>%
filter(gender != 'M' & state != 'CA',
       gender != 'F' & state != 'PH')
```

Comment: like this? `df %>% filter(!(gender == 'M' & state == 'CA'), !(gender == 'F' & state == 'PH'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the `NA`s, we need to use `%in%` instead of `==`:

```r
df %>%
  filter(
    !(gender %in% 'M' & state %in% 'CA'),
    !(gender %in% 'F' & state %in% 'PH')
  )
#    id    name gender        dob state
# r2 11     ram      M 1981-03-24    NY
# r3 12 deepika   <NA> 1987-06-14  <NA>
# r4 13 sahithi      F 1985-08-16  <NA>
# r5 14   kumar      M 1995-03-02    DC
# r6 15   scott      M 1991-06-21    DW
# r7 16     Don      M 1986-03-24    AZ
```

(Otherwise, the rows with `NA`s are removed as well.)

The reason this works is that `==` will return `NA` if either side is `NA`, but `%in%` does not:

```r
c("F", "M", NA) == "M"
# [1] FALSE  TRUE    NA
c("F", "M", NA) %in% "M"
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Another option is to `anti_join` them. I find this overkill for this specific scenario, but if you're keeping a table of paired conditions to remove, this might be simpler: maintain a frame of `remove`-rows then anti-join them:

```r
remove <- tibble(gender=c("M", "F"), state=c("CA","PH"))
df %>%
  anti_join(remove, by = c("gender", "state"))
#    id    name gender        dob state
# r2 11     ram      M 1981-03-24    NY
# r3 12 deepika   <NA> 1987-06-14  <NA>
# r4 13 sahithi      F 1985-08-16  <NA>
# r5 14   kumar      M 1995-03-02    DC
# r6 15   scott      M 1991-06-21    DW
# r7 16     Don      M 1986-03-24    AZ
```